# Python OpenCV find squares using contours

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to find all squares in a scrabble playfield using OpenCV.

This is the input image:

[image: Input image]

I managed to transform this image into a 500x500 grayscale picture:

[image: Grayscale image]

After that I tried to detect the squares.

First I tried using `thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 1, 11, 2)` resulting in this image:

[image: Adaptive threshold]

Then I did `_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)` to find the squares. I filtered the contour areas bigger than 500 but smaller than 1000.

Then I draw the found contours on the original image to see if I found all squares:

[image: Result]

I saw that almost all squares got detected, but for some reason the lighter colored ones could not be detected.
I would like to know how to find the remaining lighter squares or if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've got 500x500 grayscale picture, why do you need all these complications? You have a picture, you know there are 15 rows and 15 columns, just split the picture into the separate squares and you'll get your board.

There's no need to do any OpenCV analysis, once you have your squares, you can be 100% sure that square #0 has markings as well as squares #3, 7 and so on.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out after I posted this, tho it would be still good to know how to do this with OpenCV analysis. Just to learn something